# Deploy a layout over android soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have created a keyboard which has buttons to change to emojis keyboard and to change themes respectively. I have created layout regarding those in xml file but I don't know how to inflate them. I have tried this to inflate layout on that button click but nothing happens.

```
menuBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.theme_layout, null, false);
            //inflate here
        }
    });
```

What should I do in order to inflate the layout?
Also, I have to inflate it over keyboard view not any normal view.

Here is screenshot of keyboard:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function inflates and throw away the result. You have to store the result in a View variable and than modify your view tree with this variable. Can be like that

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) yourCurView.getParent();
                    parent.removeView(yourCurView);
                    parent.addView(yourNewView);
```

To switch between keyboards use [KeyboardView.setKeyboard()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html#setKeyboard(android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard)).

Comment: It deploys the layout but the layout inflated is not doing anything even if it is declared in an activity. What should I do in that case?

Comment: If you are talking about custom keyboard there is not activity, but a service. System expects an inflated view to be returned in [InputMethodService.onCreateInputView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onCreateInputView())